# Time & Space Efficient Dictionary Implementation

Tags: java, dictionary, tree

I am trying to create a space and time efficient implementation of a common character dictionary in Java.

The dictionary, rather than being ordered from A-Z, will somehow group all the words together that contain a letter "A", "B" etc. The application needs to be able to remove all words containing whatever letter the user enters. So if a user enters "L", all words containing "L" are removed.

I have created:

Set< String> dictionary - stores all of the words.

Map< Character, Set< String> > - maps chars A to Z which each have a set containing all the words from dictionary that contain that letter.

Example:

```
dictionary {"AAB", "ABB", "BBC", "BBA", "CBB"}
```

Map:

```
A - "AAB", "ABB", "BBA" 

B - "AAB", "ABB", "BBC", "BBA", "CBB"

C - "BBC", "CBB"
```

If the user selects "A", the set of A is removed from the dictionary and the map is rebuilt, awaiting the user to remove another letter.

My problem is that this will lead to huge data duplication and inefficiencies. I cannot think of another way to efficiently implement this. I have been hinted that trees may be a way to solve this but I cannot see how their implementation would be more efficient in both time & space.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: seems to be ok, just go ahead with it. There is no duplication as the same string objects (words) will be referred from all the Sets. Also you might reduce overhead by using Lists instead of Sets.

Comment: Use a tree, with each data node containing a list of nodes below it.  You'd have an A node that has below it AB, AC, AA, and AD.  This way to block out all A words, you simply remove the A node.  to filter out all AD words, remove the AD node, etc.  You WILL have to code this yourself, I believe, but it should be efficient.

Comment: Radix Tree? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree

Comment: @Sheriff - Wouldn't that lead to the same duplication? Let's say I had the word "CAT", it would need to go under the "A" node but also in the "C" and "T" nodes. Thanks

Comment: @Palo you're right.  I misunderstood your problem.  You could do something like `for( String str: strList) { if str.contains(charChoice) strList.remove(str);}`  but that's just a linear sort, and I think it'd have massive overhead for each removal.

Comment: @Sheriff Yeah I think I'm going to go with my original implementation and see how it works out. The dictionary.txt has about 50,000 entries though but I can't see any other tree implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should use a **trie**. It's a pretty straightforward tree-structure, details and implementation examples can be found on wikipedia:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree

Depending on your needs, you could further improve space-efficiency using suffix compression or packing (beware, after you've done those, your trie will no longer be modifyable).

Also, I would consider if you actually have to delete all items from your dictionary-structure that do not match the given prefix. With tries, you could eliminate invalid words by simply "looking" at the relevant subtree and only considering those entries.

hope it helped